# Cannot initialize tessdata path for OCR using tess-two in Android

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I am developing an Android OCR project. In my project, I am using tess-two. But I am having problem with initializing trainned data from tessdata folder for tess-two.

I installed tess-two in grandle like this

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.2'
}
```

Then I tried detect text from bitmap like this

```
public String detectText(Bitmap bitmap) {

        TessBaseAPI tessBaseAPI = new TessBaseAPI();
        tessBaseAPI.setDebug(true);
        tessBaseAPI.init(DATA_PATH, "eng"); //Init the Tess with the trained data file, with english language

        //For example if we want to only detect numbers
        tessBaseAPI.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, "1234567890");
        tessBaseAPI.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_BLACKLIST, "!@#$%^&*()_+=-qwertyuiop[]}{POIU" +
                "YTREWQasdASDfghFGHjklJKLl;L:'\"\\|~`xcvXCVbnmBNM,./<>?");


        tessBaseAPI.setImage(bitmap);

        String text = tessBaseAPI.getUTF8Text();

        tessBaseAPI.end();

        return text;
    }
```

That is fired when a button is clicked. My activity includes only that function. The problem is with data path variable.

This is my project structure

[image]

Yes, I added two tessdata folders to demonstrate two scenarios.

First try. I set DATA_PATH like this

```
DATA_PATH = Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath()+"/data/";
```

That gives me "Data path does not exist!" error. So I found these solutions [Tesseract OCR Android tessdata directory not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282731/tesseract-ocr-android-tessdata-directory-not-found) and [Get path of data directory(android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568045/get-path-of-data-directoryandroid) .

So I tried to set DATA_PATH like this

```
DATA_PATH = Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath();
```

It gives me "Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!" error.

Then I tried this

```
DATA_PATH = Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath()+"/data/tessdata/";
```

Then I gives me this error again "Data path does not exist!".

Then I tried this way

```
DATA_PATH = Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath()+"/tessdata/";
```

It gives me this error "Data path does not exist!".

So all the ways I tried are not working. How can I initialize tessdata folder correctly? I have no idea to set the path for it.

Comment: In that link, it is saying to use like this baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/tesseract", "eng"); . It is from sdcard. , my tessdata folder is in project parent directory. So in my cause, I must reference like this? "/tessdata".

Comment: I tried it and not working.

Comment: I tried this "/data" and this "/"

Comment: When I tried this "/data", it is giving me this error "Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!". Please how can I fix it?

Comment: I tried this as well "/data/" according to doc.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your tessdata directory in your internal storage or phone memory. Then put your DATA_PATH variable as

```
DATA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";
```

And then try to run it. I've recently found out that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` may not always point to your SD card or your external storage. In my case it actually pointed to my internal storage and thus copying tessdata folder in my internal storage with the above DATA_PATH worked fine for me. So, this should directly point to your internal memory which contains the tessdata folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the files in `assets` folder and then copying them to somewhere like `/storage/emulated/0/tesseract/tessdata/` using `AssetManager`.